# IBM system x3650 m3 server machine. Ram

Tags: ibm

This machine uses 16 slots of Ram. There are installed 4 memory of ram. Each of it has 4 GB. So the whole machine has 16 GB of ram. They are placed on different slots. So the question is. Why does it matter? 2x are the same company and are placed like in slot 3 and 6 while the other 2 are the same and are placed on 12 and 15. Sth like that. What should I pay attention to while upgrading this machine and where to places other memories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://systemx.lenovofiles.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.lenovo.sysx.7945.doc%2Ft_installing_memory_module_option.html), there are actually 18 memory slots, not 16.

You must populate the memory slots in a certain order:

**Microprocessor socket 1**

Install the DIMMs in the following sequence: 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7

**Microprocessor socket 2**

Install the DIMMs in the following sequence: 12, 15, 18, 11, 14, 17, 10, 13, 16

You must also install equal amounts of memory modules for each processor. As you said, slots 3, 6, 12, and 15 are filled in your server, which are the first two slots you must populate. If you were to add 4 additional memory modules, they would go in slots 9, 2, 18, 11.

Comment: If I may also ask. What does it mean to "populate"? I have to read the manuals.

Comment: Populate is to insert or install a memory module into an empy slot.

Comment: Thanks sir. Everything is clear. Awesome. Stay safe!